# Having different javascript files share the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Now I am creating a few plugins for WordPress. All need to work separately, but I want to add an implementation to have them work together.

For starters, all the script will use a custom name to reference jQuery, that is the first part where my problem start. In WordPress I have a combined object that I want to populate with all the values. The combined object is named: `myObject`.

Now I try this but it does not work:

```
if( typeof myObject.jq !== 'undefined' )
    myObject.jq = jQuery.noConflict();

myObject.jq(document).ready(function(){

}
```

> *I get the error message **'myObject.jq'** is not a function.*

I want to further expand this with a combined ajax function, like this

```
if( typeof myObject.jq !== 'undefined' ){
    myObject.jq = jQuery.noConflict();

    myObject.ajaxcall = function(action){
        var dfr = myObject.jq.Deferred();
        myObject.jq.ajax({
            url:myObject.ajaxurl,
            type:'post',
            data:{
                action:action,
                face:myObject.face
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success:dfr.resolve
        });
        return dfr.promise();
    };
}

myObject.jq(document).ready(function(){
    // My code here
}
```

This completely does not work. Anyone have any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: What is the 'jq' property ? WHat does it contain already (because you testing that it is **NOT** _undefined_).

Comment: Oh that's really stupid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have the 'undefined' logic backwards. You should say `typeof myObject.jq === 'undefined'`. Although, since `jq` is expected to be a function, the better check would be `typeof myObject.jq !== 'function'`.

Answer (score 0):

For you first piece to work, you need to declare `myObject` as an `object`. And javaScript will automatically assign undefined object identifiers, so you don't need to test whether the key exists. So change your code to the following will work:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.jq = jQuery.noConflict();
myObject.ajaxcall = function(action) {
 //You function code
};

myObject.jq(document).ready(function(){
  //Your code goes here
});
```

This wil result in the following `myObject`

```
myObject
  ajaxcall: function (action) { }
  jq: function (a,b){return new d.fn.init(a,b,g)}
```

Comment: Oh no myObject was already defined in scripts above. I just had the `!==` wrong, really stupid mistake. Ryan had the correct answer.